# How to find a single word in "std::vector<char>" container

Tags: c++, search, vector, stl, find

I have a mixed binary (i.e. image) and some human readable data (i.e. HTTP header) stored in the "`std::vector<char>`" container.
(Data is separated by "CRLFCRLF (\r\n\r\n)" indicator)

Can anyone suggest a way on how to find a **start** position of "**\r\n\r\n**" in the "`std::vector<char>`" container?

Is it possible to do something like "`std::size_t pos = data.find("\r\n\r\n");` (where data is a "`std::vector<char>`")" using STL library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to put the pattern you're looking for into a container. A C string is enough.

```
std::vector<char> v = ....;
const char *crlf2 = "\r\n\r\n";
auto it = std::search(v.begin(), v.end(), crlf2, crlf2 + strlen(crlf2));
```

Anyway, after this, `it` will contain an iterator into the vector `v` where that pattern begins (or `v.end()` if the pattern is not found).

You can convert that into an index with `std::distance(v.begin(), it)` or just `it - v.begin()`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`std::search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) to search for the first occurrence of the character sequence of interest. You would have to place that sequence in an array or container.

```
std::vector<char> v = ....;
std::vector<char> start{'\r', '\n', '\r', '\n'};
auto it = std::search(v.begin(), v.end(), start.begin(), start.end());
```

Comment: It would also be possible to place the sequence in a string, which of course is another kind of char container.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
// As mentioned, you can use a basic C-style string.
// But, for convenience, an array works just as well
// Using an array allows for us to use std::begin() and std::end()
static constexpr const char DOUBLE_CLRF[]{'\r','\n','\r','\n'};

/**
 <summary>        Finds the first occurrence of "\r\n\r\n".   </summary>
 <param name="v"> Contains the char data you want to process. </param>
 <returns>        The position of the first "\r\n\r\n".       </returns>
 */
ptrdiff_t findFirstDoubleClrf(const std::vector<char>& v) {
    const auto it = std::search(v.begin(), v.end(), std::begin(DOUBLE_CLRF), std::end(DOUBLE_CLRF));
    return std::distance(v.begin(), it);
}

/**
 <summary>        Finds the last occurrence of "\r\n\r\n".    </summary>
 <param name="v"> Contains the char data you want to process. </param>
 <returns>        The position of the last "\r\n\r\n".        </returns>
 */
ptrdiff_t findLastDoubleClrf(const std::vector<char>& v) {
    const auto it = std::find_end(v.begin(), v.end(), std::begin(DOUBLE_CLRF), std::end(DOUBLE_CLRF));
    return std::distance(v.begin(), it);
}
```

Now suppose your binary data with human readable text is in your (as mentioned) `std::vector<char>` named `data`.

```
// To get the *first* match
auto pos = findFirstDoubleClrf(data);

// To get the *last* match
auto lastPos = findLastDoubleClrf(data);

// Note: std::distance returns a signed value rather than unsigned (e.g. size_t)
// You can, of course, static_cast<size_t>(pos) if desired.
```

**But** if you miss the `find()` method `std::string` offers, and you have C++17 available, `std::string_view` can be worked in without copying the entire `std::vector<char>` to offer similar functionality.

```
std::string_view sv(&data[0], data.size());
auto pos = sv.find("\r\n\r\n");
auto lastPos = sv.rfind("\r\n\r\n");
```